# Passing a variant as parameter to a function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function

```
Function convertToDict(arrayIp As Variant) As Object
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each element In arrayIp

    If dict.exists(element) Then
        dict.Item(element) = dict.Item(element) + 1
    Else
        dict.Add element, 1
    End If
Next
End Function
```

I tried to call this function from a sub

```
Dim dict As Object
varray = Range("B4:B" & finalRow - 1).Value
dict = convertToDict(varray)
```

But it throws error:

> Run time error 450, wrong number of arguments or invalid property

what is the mistake that I have done here?

I am passing a variant and result is an `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are dealing with ***Objects*** you need **Set** in both the function and the sub:

```
Function convertToDict(arrayIp As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each element In arrayIp

        If dict.exists(element) Then
            dict.Item(element) = dict.Item(element) + 1
        Else
            dict.Add element, 1
        End If
    Next
    Set convertToDict = dict
End Function

Sub qwerty()
    Dim dict As Object
    finalRow = 10
    varray = Range("B4:B" & finalRow - 1).Value
    Set dict = convertToDict(varray)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `dict` is an object, you need to use `Set` when assigning to it.  Try

```
Set dict = convertToDict(varray)
```